# Angular 6 through json and get data based on id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

**ERROR**

> ServiceDetailComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'serviceName' of undefined; at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]
>   (ServiceDetailComponent.html:3); at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as
>   updateRenderer] (core.js:11080); at checkAndUpdateView
>   (core.js:10456); at callViewAction (core.js:10692); at
>   execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634); at checkAndUpdateView
>   (core.js:10457); at callViewAction (core.js:10692); at
>   execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10655); at checkAndUpdateView
>   (core.js:10452); at callViewAction (core.js:10692);

---

**Service :**

```
import { IServices } from './../../services';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceService {

  // private _url: string = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d8suw';
  private _url: string = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1azcrc';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getServices(): Observable<IServices[]> {
    return this.http.get<IServices[]>(this._url);
  }


  getService(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<IServices[]>(this._url + id );
  }

}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceService } from '../services/service.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IServices } from 'src/app/services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-detail',
  templateUrl: './service-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-detail.component.css']
})
export class ServiceDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  service: IServices[];
  constructor(private serviceService: ServiceService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.serviceService.getService(this.id)
      .subscribe(service => {
          this.service = service;
      });

  }

}
```

**HTML Result**

```
<p>
  service-detail works!
</p>

{{ service.serviceName }}
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: `service.serviceName` might only work after the ajax request in your service has completed. Before that, that's 100% sure its undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `undefined` error since you haven't initialized a `service` property in `ServiceDetailComponent`. You initialise it in the callback function, which runs asynchronously when the server returns a response.

Check for null or use below optional syntax:

```
{{ service?.serviceName }}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i have new error : GET https://api.myjson.com/bins/1azcrc2 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That is because of invalid API URL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your naming is all over the place. `service: IService[]` --> you are expecting a list of services, so make it `services: IService[]`.
2. `this.services` property will be undefined until you get the response back from server. If you want to use it in the template, you should use `elvis` operator - which is a fancy name for `?` and looks like this: `service?.serviceName` . This in essence tells Angular not to throw an error if `service` is undefined and rerender the value once it becomes available.
3. Since `this.services` is an array, you need to loop over the items using `*ngFor` structural directive:

   `<p *ngFor="let service of services">
     {{service.serviceName}}
   </p>`

As you can see - I am not using `elvis` operator here since `*ngFor` won't render anything unless `services` value is initialized.

Comment: I want get detail service by id, getService(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<IServices[]>(this._url + id );
  }

Comment: Then your return type is wrong `<IServices[]>` signifies a list of `IService`. If you're getting one service, it should be `IService`. And why plural again? --> `IServices[]` reads like you are getting a list of `IServices` - which is a list of lists. If you make typos like that you make it harder for yourself and others to follow what is happening in your code.

Answer (score -1):

service: IServices[]; you are trying to access the property of the array of 'service'.
Refer the items in the array and then refer the property.

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand what you mean !

Comment: Please try updating your answer with a code snipped, along with explanation why it addresses the question.